# jQuery to show icon after .hide

Tags: plugins, jquery

I am using the SimpleLightbox plugin (https://wordpress.org/plugins/simplelightbox/) on a test site: http://joshrodg.com/theiveys/about.

If you click on one of the pictures, SimpleLightbox opens a larger version in a Lightbox. You'll notice that to close the Lightbox you need to click the white "X" in the upper-right hand corner, but that is directly over the page menu (where the three lines are).

So, I added some code that would remove the navigation bar from the page when the Lightbox loads, which looks like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".simplelightbox").click(function(){
        $(".burger").hide();
    })
});
```

This works because the code gets executed when someone clicks on one of the Lightbox images with the class "simplelightbox"

The problem I'm having is making the nav bar re-appear.

I have tried:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".simple-lightbox").click(function(){
        $(".burger").show();
    })
});
```

but that doesn't work - the nav bar doesn't re-appear. That one uses class .simple-lightbox (because that is the main class when the Lightbox is showing) - there is also sl-overlay, sl-wrapper, sl-image, and sl-close but none of those worked either.

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks,
Josh

Comment: I explored that post, literally copied and tweaked every suggested answer and I still get the same results...when I click the image the nav bar disappears and the Lightbox opens, but when I close the Lightbox, the nav bar is still hidden. Can you let me know which one is the solution @toscho

Comment: What does your console say?

Comment: That definitely fixes the errors, but not the behavior on the page...thanks for pointing out the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.simplelightbox').on('click', function () {
            $('.burger').addClass('active');
        });
        $('body').on('click', 'button.sl-close', function () {
            $('.burger').removeClass('active');
        });
        $('body').on('click', '.sl-overlay', function () {
            $('.burger').removeClass('active');
        });
    });
}(jQuery));
```

Not sure if this is the best solution, but it works.

This adds an `"active"` class to the `"burger"` element when one of the images is clicked because the on click is for the `simplelightbox` class...I then added some css to that class `display: none`

I am removing the `active` class with the `button.sl-close` (so we're targeting a specific button) and then `.sl-overlay` the Lightbox window itself (so when we click on any of the green space the class is also removed).

Answer (score 0):

I assume the different spellings of `.simplelightbox` and `.simple-lightbox` are typos in your question and both are correct in your code.

My first thought would be to find the function in the plugin that is fired when the white 'X' is clicked (that closes the lightbox) and add your line of code. If you don't want to edit the plugin (which would have to be done every time the plugin is updated by the vendor), I would focus on the class of the white 'X' itself. Inspecting your page, it seems to be `.sl-close`. Well, you say that didn't work.

Have you tried playing with the jQuery `toggle()` function? It alternates between `hide()` and `show()` depending on the state of the element.

The last thing I might suggest is seeing if you can reduce the size of the lightbox by about 5%, making it so it doesn't overlap with your menu in the first place.

Comment: Actually, if you look at the code `.simplelightbox` is being applied to the href of the image and `.simple-lightbox` is being applied to the Lightbox itself. Although they are similar class names, they aren't typos.

Comment: I did try the `toggle()` functionality, but it seems like that is only applicable from the same element, in other words click button A to show, click button A to hide...I'm clicking button A to show, and button B to hide.

Comment: Looking into the size of the Lightbox (at the moment)...that's something I haven't tried.

Comment: I tried the `toggle()` and the same things happens...here is the code: https://jsfiddle.net/j58x5oj4/

Answer (score 0):

Your actual button is hidden ( the link you provided ) . Right now your button is unclickable, and it's the overlay that closes your LightBox, not the close button. You have to define a width and height for it:

```
.sl-wrapper .sl-close {
    height:30px;
    width:30px
}

.button.sl-close::after {
    top:30px;
    right:30px
}
```

Then, you can use the button's class to show your Navigation menu on click:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".sl-close").click(function(){
        $(".burger").show();
    })
});
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: Hey there, I changed the name of the css file that has the Lightbox css to eliminate any confusion on the styling and then added your css with `!important` declarations (just in case the plugin's own styling was interfering), but that didn't solve the issue. When you click on an image the Lightbox opens, the nav bar is hidden, but then doesn't re-appear when the Lightbox closes.